# Google Chrome deny access to site with bad certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

For testing purposes i redirect site "google-analytics" in my hosts to developer's testing platform. But my browser Google Chrome (50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)) deny access to it.

Before, i remember on the page was button "procceed", but now it's not.

[image]

In russian, i hope you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google Analytic use HSTS, who doesn't allow to bypass https errors:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6385009?hl=en
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-12.1 : Chrome and Firefox implement the "No User Recourse".

Comment: Strange, but in Safari it possible. 
I dont understand how the HSTS restrict access. It is just one more header in response. My test site cant send it?

Ok, for now, is there a way to test some developers features on our test site to which we are redirected by hosts by google-analytics.com request?

Comment: Once the browser see the HSTS header once, it remember it. After that, any https error can't be bypassed on the website. You must use a browser who doesn't implement that, or never saw the HSTS header (or you can remove it : http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers ).

Comment: I try to delete but seems google-analytics.com is a built-in site, or i cant delete "google-analytics.com" for unknown reasons. So small problem and how much time was spent.

Comment: Yes it's built-in : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google-analytics.com&s=216.58.194.196 (see "preload")

Comment: Sure google, and it not added their own site to preload on Google chrome(?). Unreal)) Ok i try on Firefox, it ok too.

Comment: Unfortunately by this manual http://classically.me/blogs/how-clear-hsts-settings-major-browsers about:permissions is do not supported anymore by Firefox. Is there a way to remove sites from PRELOADED list in chrome or replacement of "about:permissions"?